# Regex Condition AFTER a special char

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I'm working on a Regex with php, but I have a problem :

I would like to make a condition : If you meet the "-" character, the next character must be an UPPERCASE character.

I did researches and found that we can use the condition like this : (?(?=regex)then|else)

Unfortunately, it's not working.

**Here is my Regex for the moment :**

```
[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Za-z-]*(?(?=[-])[A-Z])
```

The string have to respect the following conditions :

- First letter as UPPERCASE
- Second letter and others as LOWERCASES
- The only special character "-" is accepted
- If met, the "-" have to be follow by an UPPERCASE

Currently, with my regex, the following result is matching (but should not) : Pilar-ackerman

The string that should match would be : Pilar-Ackermam

Could someone help me plz ?

**UPDATES FROM COMMENTS**:

A string like `PilAr` is matching, and should not :(

I don't need to allow multiple "-" symbols in the input string.

Comment: And what should be matched in `Pilar-Ackerman`? The whole string? Try [`^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?:-[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mT4qQ2/1) or [`^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?:-[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/mT4qQ2/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes exactly !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Your Regex looks good thx, BUT I want to allow UPPERCASES only after a "-". Currently, with your regex, a string like "PilAr" is matching, and should not :(

Comment: Then, try [`^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/mT4qQ2/3). I just did not remove the `A-Z` range from your original regex. Note that this one will match 1 uppercase letter words like `A` or `M`. Also, I am still unsure if there can be `Pilar-Acker-Man` or not. If yes, you need `^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*$`. Also, you have not mentioned anything about Unicode - are you planning to only match ASCII letters?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thx a lot ! It did the trick :D Yes it will only match ASCII letters, and I don't need to allow multiple "-", so the first answer was perfect !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have to deal with ASCII letters and there should be only 2 max chunks separated with a `-`, you can use

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT4qQ2/3)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with zero or more lowercase ones
- `(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)?` - one or zero (due to `?` quantifier) sequences of...

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with zero or more lowercase ones
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I left only the regex that allows 1 hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[A-Z](?:[a-z]+|-[A-Z])*+$
```

Comment: This one `^[A-Z](?:[a-z]+|-[A-Z])*+$` will match a word with more than 1 hyphen, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: not in the question, not my problem.